# Comparing two arrays using hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, hashmap

So I came across a coding problem on codewar. The instruct goes
"Given two arrays a and b write a function comp(a, b) (orcompSame(a, b)) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the elements in b are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order.

Examples
Valid arrays
a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
b = [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
comp(a, b) returns true because in b 121 is the square of 11, 14641 is the square of 121, 20736 the square of 144, 361 the square of 19, 25921 the square of 161, and so on. It gets obvious if we write b's elements in terms of squares:

a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
b = [11*11, 121*121, 144*144, 19*19, 161*161, 19*19, 144*144, 19*19]
Invalid arrays
If, for example, we change the first number to something else, comp may not return true anymore:

a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
b = [132, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
comp(a,b) returns false because in b 132 is not the square of any number of a.

a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
b = [121, 14641, 20736, 36100, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
comp(a,b) returns false because in b 36100 is not the square of any number of a.

Remarks
a or b might be [] (all languages except R, Shell).
a or b might be nil or null or None or nothing (except in C++, Elixir, Haskell, PureScript, Pascal, R, Rust, Shell).
If a or b are nil (or null or None), the problem doesn't make sense so return false."

This is my solution

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

public class main {

```
public static int BiggestElement(int [] arr) {
    int result = 0;
    result = arr[0];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if(arr[i]>= result) {
            result = arr[i];
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}

public static boolean comp(int[] a, int []b) {
    int size = a.length;
    if(a.length != b.length) {
        System.out.println("They don't have the same size");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        //First we need to check which one has the biggest element
        int biggestA = 0;
        int biggestB = 0;
        System.out.println(biggestA = BiggestElement(a));
        System.out.println(biggestB = BiggestElement(b));
        
        //creating two maps 
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        //now we put every value of b inside the map
        for(int i = 0; i<a.length;i++) {
            map1.put(a[i], i);
            map2.put(b[i], i);
        }
        
        //now we do the actual comparision
        if(biggestA>biggestB) {
            for(int  i=0;i<size;i++) {
                if(!map1.containsKey(b[i]*b[i])) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for(int  i=0;i<size;i++) {
                if(!map2.containsKey(a[i]*a[i])) {
                    System.out.println("map 1 doesn't contain " + (b[i]*b[i]));
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[]{121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11};
    int[] b = new int[]{121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361};
    
    System.out.println(comp(a,b));
}
```

}

I submit my code and they did 13 test, but I failed three. Anyone has any recommendations or solution suggested to me so I can improve it.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the tests which failed

Comment: The instructions as you have posted them are a little bit garbled. Perhaps you can write them more clearly (and concisely).

Comment: The weird thing about code wards was that it didn't show why my test failed. I came here for a better solution if there is any

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your approach above, you are relying on map keys to keep track of the array values. However, maps can't have duplicate keys, so whenever you add a value to the map for a given key, the old one is replaced.

So the following arrays will compare equally (which they are not - one of the `4s` in `b` should be a `16`.

```
int[] a = {1,2,2,3,4,4}; 
int[] b = {1,4,4,9,16,4};
```

Well, here is one approach.  I'm fairly certain there are others that are probably more efficient.  The main point is it keeps a count of each time the value appeared and uses that count as part of the comparison process.

- First, check to ensure arrays are non-null and the lengths are the same as any routine would probably do that.
- Then find which array has the squares (although this should be known before calling the method).
- Then compute a count of the number of times each square of `n` will occur.
- Then for each value `n`, subtract 1 from the value count.
- If that value becomes negative, return false immediately since the one-to-one mapping doesn't exist.
- Otherwise, run thru the values and if any are non-zero, return false.

```
public static boolean comp(int[] a, int[] b) {

    if (a == null || b == null ||
            (a.length != b.length)) {
                   return false;
    }

    int maxVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int maxSquare = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        maxVal = Math.max(vals[i], maxVal);
        maxSquare = Math.max(squares[i], maxSquare);
    }
    // swap them if required
    if (maxVal > maxSquare) {
        int[] temp = squares;
        squares = vals;
        vals = temp;
    }
    Map<Integer, Integer> mapA = new HashMap<>();
    for (int el : a) {
        mapA.compute(el * el, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
    }
    
    for (int el : b) {
        if (mapA.computeIfPresent(el, (k, v) -> v - 1) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i : mapA.values()) {
        if (i != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    
}
```

Comment: Wow, I like that you use the max functions from the Math class. Thank you!

Comment: I just update the first part of my answer to address your method.

Comment: Thanks! I give you an upvote I'm new to this platform

Answer (score -1):

here is the code：

```
public static boolean comp(int[] a, int []b) {
    if(a.length != b.length) {
        System.out.println("They don't have the same size");
        return false;
    }
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int i: a) {
        set.add(i);
        set.add(i * i);
    }
    for(int i: b)
    {
        if(!set.contains(i) && !set.contains(i * i))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `Sets` since they hide duplicates.  So if one array had `2,2,2,4,4` and the other had `4,4,16,16,16` using sets would make them equal, which they aren't.  And you're supposed to use `HashMap`  Note: someone else downvoted you and that may be why.